# string cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting a "string cannot be resolved to a type" error in my code.

```
public class Main {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  FormLetter template;
  template = new FormLetter();
  template.print();
  template.composeFormLetter(Sean, Colbert, God);
  template.print();

 }

}

class FormLetter
 {
  public void print(){
    System.out.println(to + candidate + from);

  }  

  public void composeFormLetter(string t, string c, string f){

   to = t;
   candidate = c; 
   from = f;
  } 
   private string to;
   private string candidate;
   private string from;

  }
```

Comment: For future reference, be sure to post the entire compiler error message in your question if present, to make it easier to pinpoint what's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` is capitalized in Java.  You cannot use lowercase `string`.  (That's C#)

**Side question:**
How is the following compiling at all?

```
template.composeFormLetter(Sean, Colbert, God);
```

Comment: Ok, I corrected the string issue. template.composeFormLetter(Sean, Colbert, God); is leaving an error:    Multiple markers at this line
    - God cannot be resolved
    - Colbert cannot be 
     resolved
    - Sean cannot be 
     resolved

Comment: @chief - String literals are supposed to have double quotes around them.  (Side answer - it is not ...)

Comment: @chief, `"God"`, `"Sean"`, `"Colbert"`  You need to put `Strings` inside of quotation marks.

Comment: Alright in the console it returns: nullnullnull and then god colbert sean.

Comment: @chief, that's what it's supposed to do?

Comment: god colbert sean - is what I was expecting.  I am not sure why I am also getting nullnullnull first.

Comment: @chief, Well, you call `template.print()` twice.  The first time all of the variables are `null`, and the second time they have values.

Comment: @chief, also, you should check the green checkmark next to my answer to show that it is the one that helped you answer your question.